# Bootstrap MVC4 Fixed Left Naigation Menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-layout

I am trying to create UI structure for Bootstrap admin template which contains left menu and right content section(Typically partial view) using MVC4.The application needs to accommodate more than 50 menus and it will increase dynamically in feature. So i have decided to go with below structure and i don't want to re-render left panel menus.I have top bar fixed header which will display lots of notification details with respect to user.My problems are i don't want to make API calls to get the notification details for every time when i click left menu which will fetch the details from lots of table in DB. So the only solution is not to refresh the left menu and top bar header(which are defined in Layout file). How can i achieve this.Any solution would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: You want to refresh top and left menus only? That's not possible. Use AJAX, that's what it is for.

Comment: No. Just want to know any other better approach apart from rendering as partial view.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX seems the solution as Stan suggested in the comment.
So first load jquery, then in the razor page render your content from an action (Html.Action) that returns a partial view.

Then when user clicks that menu item make a call from client with jquery to that action so you return PartialContentView, and replace the content section with server response.

Comment: Thanks eugen. That's the approach am following now.My question is "are there any other solution available to achieve the results".

Comment: @Oasis Other solution would be to use `iframe` elements but that would be horrible approach.